# How to combine multiple rows into single row in Informatica Cloud?

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud

The data from the column :

```
Column1
Row1
Row2
Row3
```

The expected output is :

```
Row1,Row2,Row3
```

The use case is that there are n rows where n>3.

This should be done on the Informatica cloud itself. There are few solutions found on the web but they don't apply for the Informatica cloud version all of them are written for the Desktop version.

Comment: Does cloud version have expression, sorter, aggregator? That's all you need to convert row to columns.

Comment: Yes, it has all the above three.

Comment: i added a solution below.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using below steps

1. First of all identify a key on which you want to concat. I will assume its id column. Order by this field using sorter. Data will look like -

```
id row_info
1  row1
1 row2
1 row3
2 row21
2 row 22
```

2. Use an expression transformation. Create below ports-

```
id  = id
rowinfo = rowinfo 
v_concat= iif (id = prev_id, rowinfo ||','||v_concat,rowinfo )
prev_id = id
o_concat = v_concat
```

Data output should look like -

```
id row_info   v_concat
1  row1 row1
1 row2 row1,row2
1 row3 row1,row2,row3
2 row21 row21
2 row22 row21,row22
```

3. Next use an aggregator to let only last row with all concatenated values out. Group by id.
   Data output should look like -

```
id o_concat
1 row1,row2,row3
2 row21,row22
```

4. In target, from agg transformation, link id column to id and o_concat to rowinfo column to get concatenated output.

Now, if you do not have id column, you can pass dummy column or remove column id from above logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can just join them together using two instances of the same table. Unless you have a common key between the rows you want to join, this will only work if you only have 2 rows in your table; otherwise you will generate a cartesian product.

Comment: This should work when you know how many row we have and if its unknown or many, then there will be an issue.